# AttributeError: 'MainScreen' object has no attribute 'iptHpIdx'

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, kivy, attributeerror

I am currently trying to develop a test app by kivy. I am using python 2.7 . My code below returns

> AttributeError: 'MainScreen' object has no attribute 'iptHpIdx'.

Could anyone please help me on this error? I just suspected that usage of self is wrong but I spent too long time to figure it out and still I have no clue on the reason why this occurs. 
Thank you so much for your help in advance!

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')
import numpy as np
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen






class MainScreen(Screen):

    screenmanager = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        iptHpIdx = TextInput(text = '', multiline=False, font_size=50)
        btnToPoint = Button(text='input')

        btnToPoint.bind(on_press=self.IptAct)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')  # syntax(padding=10, orientation='vertical')

        layout.add_widget(iptHpIdx)
        layout.add_widget(btnToPoint)
        layout.add_widget(canvas)

        self.add_widget(layout)

    def IptAct(self, btn):
        global HpHist
        self.btnToPoint.text = 'Your input ' + self.iptHpIdx.text

        try:
            val = int(self.iptHpIdx.text)
            HpHist.append(self.iptHpIdx.text)
            print 'HpHistAf', HpHist
        except ValueError:
            print "That's not an int!"
            pass

        print HpHist

        plt.clf()

        plt.plot(HpHist)
        canvas.draw_idle()

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sc1 = MainScreen(name='MainPage')
        sm.add_widget(sc1)
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HpHist = []

    (fig, axe) = plt.subplots()
    canvas = fig.canvas
    Test().run()}
```

Comment: Could you please post a screen shot of the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `self.iptHpIdx` in `IptAct()` function but you never created that on your `__init__()`, you need to create it as `self.iptHpIdx`. So change your `__init__()` to:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.iptHpIdx = TextInput(text = '', multiline=False, font_size=50)
    self.btnToPoint = Button(text='input')

    self.btnToPoint.bind(on_press=self.IptAct)

    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')  # syntax(padding=10, orientation='vertical')

    layout.add_widget(self.iptHpIdx)
    layout.add_widget(self.btnToPoint)
    layout.add_widget(canvas)

    self.add_widget(layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare ObjectProperty and hook it up the child widgets. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Snippets

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    ms_iptHpIdx = ObjectProperty(None)
    ms_btnToPoint = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.ms_iptHpIdx = iptHpIdx
        self.ms_btnToPoint = btnToPoint
        ...

    def IptAct(self, btn):
        global HpHist
        self.ms_btnToPoint.text = 'Your input ' + self.ms_iptHpIdx.text

        try:
            val = int(self.ms_iptHpIdx.text)
            HpHist.append(self.ms_iptHpIdx.text)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg


class MainScreen(Screen):

    ms_iptHpIdx = ObjectProperty(None)
    ms_btnToPoint = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        iptHpIdx = TextInput(text='', multiline=False, font_size=50)
        btnToPoint = Button(text='input')

        self.ms_iptHpIdx = iptHpIdx
        self.ms_btnToPoint = btnToPoint

        btnToPoint.bind(on_press=self.IptAct)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')  # syntax(padding=10, orientation='vertical')

        layout.add_widget(iptHpIdx)
        layout.add_widget(btnToPoint)
        layout.add_widget(canvas)

        self.add_widget(layout)

    def IptAct(self, btn):
        global HpHist
        self.ms_btnToPoint.text = 'Your input ' + self.ms_iptHpIdx.text

        try:
            val = int(self.ms_iptHpIdx.text)
            HpHist.append(self.ms_iptHpIdx.text)
            print('HpHistAf', HpHist)
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not an int!")

        print(HpHist)

        plt.clf()

        plt.plot(HpHist)
        canvas.draw_idle()


class TestKivyMatplotlib(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='MainPage'))
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HpHist = []

    (fig, axe) = plt.subplots()
    canvas = fig.canvas
    TestKivyMatplotlib().run()
```

### Output

[image]